# Why is pip failing to install tbb

Tags: python, macos, pip, tbb

I am trying to install [umap-learn](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap) on my machine. But, I run into problems when installing [tbb](https://pypi.org/project/tbb/), which is a required package.

#### Installing from PyPI with pip

When I do,

```
pip install tbb
```

I get the error:

```sh
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tbb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tbb
```

#### Downloading wheel from PyPI and installing

I downloaded the wheel from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tbb/2019.0/#files), and then tried installing directly with:

```sh
pip install tbb-2019.0-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_12_intel.macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl
```

I get the error:

```sh
ERROR: tbb-2019.0-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_12_intel.macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl is not 
a supported wheel on this platform.
```

My machine is a Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6).

#### Help

1. Does this mean that tbb is not supported for my OS?
2. Is there some other package I am missing that is causing the installation to fail?
3. Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: The file name would suggest it requires at least macOS 10.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting out the tbb requirement in the requirement.txt file allows UMAP to be installed without tbb. UMAP can run without tbb, for the most part.